# View html file thats on my computer from iphone/android?

Tags: android, html, iphone

So, ive made a little python program that gets data from my flight simulator and puts it on a a html page. How can I access this html file with my mobile device? I was thinking over LAN but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: host it from your computer and go to that link?

Comment: How would I go by doing that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about setting up a web server

Comment: Id rather not use a web server. maybe just access it over the LAN

Comment: have you tried [Googling how to set up a web server in python?](http://google.com)

Comment: Is there any way I can do this without setting up a web server?

Comment: a webserver doesn't need to be web facing, you can have a webserver that is local to your home network. [have a look at this simple python web server](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python) which should be perfect for your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to have some type of web server, such as Apache.

Once you install Apache, just edit your Python script to save the HTML file to /var/www/index.html

You will then be able to access the HTML page using your computers local IP address on any other computers/devices on your LAN. Simply type the local IP address (usually 192.168.1.X) into your device's browser.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Very good! however, Ive released this program for people to use and a lot of them requested the ablity to view the page on their iphone. So does that mean they will have to do this?

Comment: it seems a bit of a waste to go through the pain of installing an Apache server for serving a simple HTML document, when the OP has mentioned he knows python and [there is a very simple python web server](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python)

Comment: True, but Apache is fairly lightweight, and gives the OP an option to add pages to his/her "website", if he/she so desires.

Comment: I'll probably go with the python one.